# ggplot2; Creating a boxplot from raw count data

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I'm trying to create a boxplot in ggplot2 from a data frame, which contains information about count data from multiple samples. In my case, for each of 6 samples, a count is recorded for each gene.

So it would look like this:

```
df <- data.frame(sample(c(1:100), 20, replace = T), sample(c(1:100), 20, replace = T),
                 sample(c(1:100), 20, replace = T), sample(c(1:100), 20, replace = T),
                 sample(c(1:100), 20, replace = T), sample(c(1:100), 20, replace = T))
names(df) <- paste0("Sample-", c(1:6))
rownames(df) <- paste0("Gene-", c(1:20))
```

Here's what I've tried:

`bp <- ggplot(df, aes(x = names(df), y = )) + geom_boxplot()`

but I have 0 idea what to put for the y value. Literally no clue. I'm pretty sure I'm not even indicating the x-axis properly. I'd appreciate some help with this very basic problem. I'm sorry for such a simple question.

Comment: Are you trying to create a different boxplot for each sample?

Comment: @heds1: Yes, but want to plot them all on the same chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ggplot` works best when data are in tidy, "long" format as opposed to "wide" format. You can get samples into one column and their values into another using `tidyr::gather`:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1001) # for reproducible example data
# generate df here as in your question

df %>% 
  gather(Sample, Count) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Sample, Count)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm downloading the tidyverse library right now. Will try it in a few minutes. What does the %>% signify?

Comment: `tidyverse` is just a quick way to load several related packages that are often used together. It isn't always necessary if you only need one or two (`tidyr` and `ggplot2` in this case). `%>%` is [the pipe](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/pipes.html).

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 <- df %>% 
  gather(sample, value)

ggplot(df2, aes(sample, value)) +
  geom_boxplot() + coord_flip()
```

[image]